# Parquet pyarrow schema to Glue schema AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, parquet, pyarrow

I am trying to find a way to convert a pyarrow schema from a parquet file on s3 to a viable Glue schema.

To put it in context, I have a bunch of locations on S3 with parquet files which are not structured properly to be parsed by a crawler and I want to create custom Glue tables calling the Glue Catalog API with a specified schema.

I thought about using pyarrow to read a parquet file and then create the Glue table using that schema, but I'm having compatibility issues.

Another option would be to use a crawler, but not sure how you can use a crawler just to find out the schema from a location.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Glue Crawler support parquet in S3. Just point the crawler to the location of your parquet files, and it should be able to infer the schema automatically.

More info in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/define-crawler.html).

Comment: I don't think I can use a Glue crawler, because my s3 structure is not well formed. It looks something like this s3://bucket/<table>/<partition_x>/<subtable>/<sub_subtable>/data/*. parquet and then... at sub_subtable level I have /profiling/p1.csv, p2.csv and i need to create and maintain schemas for all sub_subtables and those csv's.